# Can I use existing curves with the "Stroke method -> Curve" in "Texture Paint"?

Tags: bezier-curves, texture-painting

***Curve*** stroke in the ***Texture Paint*** mode is very handy at times. In my case I want to use an existing curve instead of creating one by hand. However it does not show in the Paint stroke curve selection menu. Is there a way to use existing curves to project a brush stroke on texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stroke method curves, though stored and named for recall, do not function as regular curve objects or can they be converted to regular curve objects. This is actually something I asked for as a feature request - that they be able to be converted to and from stroke curves just like mesh objects can be converted to curves and back again.